# Let the Game (singleton) handles the Components to add to the game

Tags: xna

I have a class 'Bullet' implementing the DrawableGameComponent. What I want is, that the Bullet add itself to the Game. My Game is a Singleton. So I thought I figured it out, but still getting errors.

The Code:

Bullet.cs

```
 public class Bullet : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Speed { get; set; }

    public Bullet(Game game) : base(game)
    {

    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        Position += Speed;
        Game1.getInstance().addBullet(this);

    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        Texture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Bullet");

        base.LoadContent();
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Shoot();

        Position = new Vector2(Position.X, Position.Y);
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Speed = new Vector2(2, 0);
        base.Initialize();
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position, Color.White);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

And in my Game1.cs which is a singleton, i do the following:

```
public void addBullet(Bullet b)
    {
        Components.Add(b);

    }
```

Unfortunately i'm getting this error:
Cannot add the same game component to a game component collection multiple times.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should edit your question title, you'd probably get more help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear, did you remove it from the game component collection before trying to add it again ?

Now I think this is a bad idea, on your game you will certainly fire many times per second, adding and removing a game component at such rate is not wise. Also a game component *per bullet* is clearly too much.

Maybe you could do something like the following :

- Create a BulletRendererComponent (or whatever you want to call it) and add it to your game,
- Whenever a bullet needs to be fired, notify that component of it
- Finally, this component should be responsible for drawing alive bullets, discard old ones etc ...

**Update**

My previous sayings might not be optimal, it should rather be a sprite renderer than a bullet renderer, here's a quick and dirty sample of how I think I'd do it, try to innovate on this.

```
// This class would render all your sprites
// You would add only one instance of it to your game
class CharacterRenderer : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public List<Character> Characters;

    void Draw()
    {
        foreach (var character in Characters)
        {
            foreach (var element in character.Elements)
            {
                // Add your logic here, checks etc ...
                DrawElement(element);
            }
        }    
    }

    private void DrawElement(Element element)
    {
        // IMO that's all there should be on your renderer, i.e. it just renders
    }
}

// Your sprite
class Character
{
    public List<Element> Elements;
}

// Your sprite elements (or parts)
class Element
{
    private Texture Texture;
    private Vector2 Position;
}
```

So whenever the status of your sprite changes (fires for instance) you would modify its elements, so add an element to its elements list whenever he sends a bullet.

Then the renderer would render all sprites elements blindly (should not care more than drawing or not sprites elements). Letting a character draw itself is generally not good, it's probably better to have a renderer of a certain class of items. (separation of concerns ?)

Note that it's not really following good OOP principles, you might a need a bigger infrastructure if you want to really make things clean.

A few principles here might help you here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Programming_principles

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It al make sense, I realy tried to implement it your way, but I cannot visualize how your 'BulletRendererComponent' would look like. Can you give a little example? thnx anyway, i was struggling with this for a couple days